# FCM: Message sent but not received

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

tried to solve this myself. spent like an hour or so still no result.

Got me old code of a previous project regarding FCM. however the code was and still working on it's app. though i managed to transfer the code to my new project. but it won't work here.

Now i know APN's are weird and complicated. but it's more of a memorized situation for me.

Things i have done:
- Uploaded my personal .p12 to my firebase project
- Enabled "Push Notifications" in app capabilities 
- Imported and used UserNotifications framework on appdelegate.swift

Here's how my **AppDelegate** look like:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import StoreKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    override init() {
        super.init()
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            // not really needed unless you really need it FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
            // ...
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }





        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default



        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gateway") as! gatewayViewController
       window!.rootViewController = viewController

        return true
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        // if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        //      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        //  }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        //if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        //    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        //}//

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

Okay so with this code you get the devices **Firebase registration token**, i copied my code and used it on **Cloud Functions** to send a test message, here's how my CF looks like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

var registrationToken = 'f8fWx_sANVM:APA91bEd46drxiBvHLZd5YKVClQr91oubzJKOyXE1LNgxOsi3ihUw31yEJL6prHKm-A83B1N1sr2GOff3P9tUsRNhCpG7_VMRlDUDfthIcwkDUgzKPV5NZtlo6pcpxsvD9ZgYlPqibNp';

 var payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "just published new Word",
        body: "Hii",
      }
    };


// registration token.
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
    // the contents of response.
    return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  }); 



 });
```

Okay so far after hitting the **helloWorld** url, my console gets this:

> Successfully sent message: { results: [ { messageId: '0:1537714204565821%b3b8835bb3b8835b' } ],
>     canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
>     failureCount: 0,
>     successCount: 1,
>     multicastId: 8154206809408282000 }
>
> Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Last time on my previous project it took 20ms at it's very best. I still can't figure this out. Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're using a HTTP(S) triggered Cloud Function, which means your code must send a response. Since your code doesn't do that, the function runs for 60s and then gets terminated by the Cloud Functions environment. This means you pay for more time than you actually need, so you'll want to fix it.

For example:

```
// registration token.
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
    // the contents of response.
    //return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    res.status(200).send(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  });
```

This will get rid of the message in the Cloud Functions logs, and ensures you only pay for the time you actually need.

Comment: I'm no javascript expert but could this be a related problem to Cloud Functions? or the .p12 stuff? I get the response when i hit helloWorld but i still don't get the message on my device.

Comment: The solution I posted should get rid of the "Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'" message in your logs. It is not related to the message not being received, as the message was already being sent successfully  (as shown by "failureCount: 0, successCount: 1" in the response).